# INSERT multiple rows with Sequelize Raw query replacements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to insert multiple rows of data with `sequelize.query` but it only inserts the first row.

Code:

```
connection.query(
    'INSERT INTO product (a, b) VALUES (?);',
    [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],
    (...args) => console.log(args)
);
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on github:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9050#issuecomment-365855299

I should have changed the code to this:

```
connection.query(
    'INSERT INTO product (a, b) VALUES ?;',
    [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]],
    (...args) => console.log(args)
);
```